# Why am i getting this segmentation fault error?

Tags: c

i am trying to use this code to ordinate arrays in a specific way, but i am always getting a segmentation fault on line 25, but i don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void bq(int* v, int s, int e);

int main(void){
  int* v;
  for(int i = 10; i <= 30; i = i + 10){
    v = (int*) malloc (i*sizeof(int));
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        v[j] = j;
    bq(v, 0, i-1);
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++){
        printf("%d ", v[k]);
    }
    free(v);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

void bq(int* v, int s, int e){
  if (e+s+1 > 2){
    int m = (e+s+1) / 2;
    bq(v, m+1, e);
    bq(v, s, m-1);
    int aux = v[e];
    v[e] = v[m];
    v[m] = aux;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get support here, it is strongly recommended to show that you've made efforts to resolve your problem. So... what have you done so far to understand your issue?

Comment: @jmr I actually don't know what to do really, i used ggdb to see which line is giving me the error and it said it was on line 25, but i don't see how can i get a segmentation fault here, I'm calling a recurrence of the function but it's not i can't access the v array, so i don't understand why i am getting this error, and especially on this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `printf` statement to the top of your `bq` function:

```
void bq(int* v, int s, int e) {
    printf("e=%d, s=%d,  e+s+1=%d\n", e, s, e + s + 1);
    if (e + s + 1 > 2) {
```

When you run your program, you'll see this is the output;

```
e=9, s=0,  e+s+1=10
e=9, s=6,  e+s+1=16
e=9, s=9,  e+s+1=19
e=9, s=10,  e+s+1=20
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
e=9, s=11,  e+s+1=21
...
```

In other words, the `bq` function converges to just invoking itself recursively with the same parameters: `bq(v, 9, 11)`.  But since `9+11+1` is always greater than `2`, it's in an infinite recursive loop. Otherwise known as Stack Overflow. The end result is you run out of stack memory and the program crashes.

My psychic powers suggest this line:

```
if (e+s+1 > 2){
```

Was intended to express, "if I have at least two elements in the range of v[s..e]".  In which case, it should read:

```
if (e-s+1 > 2){
```

Not sure about the rest of your program being correct, but that's a start.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, i changed the condition and I am not getting the segmentation fault error anymore, you really helped me a lot.

Comment: And I hope you learned the most basic of debugging techniques - adding `print` statements to display program state.